# How to play multiple live streaming in android application?

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp

I should develop an android app to play multiple rtsp live streaming in android application. The target is obviously a security multiple cams viewer as an app for an android mobile device. So far I got several solutions for either live streaming or single streaming, but none seems to work with both requirements. In particular:

a) android VideoView class can handle multiple movies but can't handle live streams (it seems to be waiting forever for the end of the stream?)

b) libVLC handles multiple live streams but overlaps them all on the same video area (I tried different layout schemas that may push the video on different screen areas, but in any case all videos are rendered overlapped

my goal is to have each live stream rendered over its own portion of the screen (either stretched or clipped, so far any solution would be good) with (in)decent frame rate (anything above 1 frame per second could be ok) and minimal delay. How would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use ExoPlayer for this kind of purpose. There are some libraries out there that decode RTSP but I personally used ExoPlayer for RTSP and I was very happy with it.

Read more here: [ExoPlayer - RTSP Support](https://exoplayer.dev/rtsp.html)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Due to my limited (null) knowledge of kotlin it took me some time to understand, build and test the exo sample programs, and yet the result is still incomplete: the demo works on sized movies and replacing the url with a rtsp url from a videocam the screen remains black as if waiting for some movie termination. But at least exoplayer is supposed to be able to handle rtsp, so I think that going through the link you provided I should be able, sooner or later, to learn how to play one or more rtsp streams. Please, whish me good luck! ;)